# Base64-Gzip Encoding and decoding

Tags: php, json, encoding, base64, gzip

I have been intercepting an app traffic.While doing so, I saw the app send a request to its server in Encrypted format.

I saw header in that request as
request:

```
`eNp1VGtPGzEQ/C/3mUS27x2pUmkLlKZB4VmIIp18thPc3CO1fdAD8d+7Z18gKeFbsjM7O17P+dlb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`
```

Request-encoding: base64-gzip
Accept-Encoding: gzip

I have tried using the gzdecode() and base64_decode() in php to decrypt the request data.But i was unable to obtain any result.Suggest me a better way to decrypt it or if i was wrong in something,comment below.

UPDATE:I have tried your idea base64 decode+ inflate [here](https://www.samltool.com/decode.php) .Didn't gave me any result.

Comment: If this is app traffic, then ask the writer of the app.

Comment: The app dev is not available in contact.I believe this is a good question.If u know kindly answer!.Thank You

Comment: [Encoding isn't encryption!](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded) I fixed the tag.

Answer (score 0):

It is Base 64 encoded, but after that it is not gzip encoded. It is zlib encoded. This would be the "Deflate" encoding as specified in HTTP.

Comment: Intresting,but i am not familiar with cryptography! can you suggest me some functions in php manual to decode! :)

Comment: It's not cryptography. It's encoding and compression. `base64_decode` and `gzuncompress`. I know nothing about php, so I found those using google. You should try it sometime.